# How do I run Google App Script in debug mode when submitting on Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I run the GAS associated with submitting from Google Form,
Please let me know how to do it in debug mode.
I want to see various data such as what kind of content is received from the form,
It's troublesome to write every Logger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) The expectation on Stack Overflow is that the user asking a question not only does research to answer their own question but also shares that research, code attempts, and results. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your issue is you have some kind of event which needs to be passed in order for you script to be able to run. (This I am guessing is why you cannot just use the debug tool in the IDE.)

An alternative I guess would be using chrome dev tools.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StackDriver console to log all message persistently.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  console.log(e);
  // your code here.
}
```

Inside the Script Editor, go to View > Stackdriver Logging to view the logged messages.

Comment: OK, I'll try it.